# symbolic links in networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I would like to create the equivalent of symbolic links in a Python [networkx](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) graph.

By default, each node in a networkx graph has an ID, and the graph is stored internally as a dictionary where each key is an ID and each value has extra information about the node.

A separate internal array of ID pairs (id1, id2) stores the edge information.

This setup is not satisfactory for me.  My nodes can be identified by multiple names, so instead of having one ID per node, I need to have multiple IDs.

I think the best solution is to have some sort of symbolic link in my networkx graphs.  A secondary ID could point to the primary ID, and networkx could internally look to the primary ID whenever it encounters a secondary one.

For example, the graph object would look like:

```
{
    "tim": tim_networkx_node_object,
    "timmy": "tim",
}
```

But how can I accomplish this in a robust way?  I am okay with monkeypatching.  The important thing is that it works well.  All ideas are welcome.

Comment: Is it possible you could also have a `timothy`->`timmy` mapping there?

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to support that, but it is not an absolute requirement.

Comment: I'm guessing your best bet is a custom dict-like class but it'll be a lot at work - start from reading: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/classes/graph.py#L179 - you'd need to keep the actual "consolidated" mapping available so all the traversals/algo's work as expected, but behind the scenes, augment it with your synonymns... have fun :)

Comment: Could you just create the name->id mapping outside of networkx and translate the names to node ids before you create or interact with the graph?

Comment: @Aric That seems like the best solution at this point.  I have a wrapper around the graph class that has a lookup mapping on the side.

Comment: @NinjaPuppy So it sounds like I need to overwrite `node_dict_factory` with my custom dict maker, but I don't know if this would give me any advantages over the less invasive method.

Comment: mareoraft - I'd prefer @Aric's approach if it's feasible for your requirements. However, it does mean that *any* query you make against it, you have to make sure that any nodes you receive etc... are always mapped to the node that's used in the graph... eg: If you receive input from somewhere that's "timmy" you're going to have to catch an operation that makes that the correct node, while with a custom `dict`, you can do it behind the scenes... just depends on your situation I guess...